# shlex splitting on curly/smart quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, shlex

Trying to split a string by whitespace, while preserving contents enclosed in curly/smart quotes (“”), by using **shlex** module in Python 3.6.3. However, it does not work properly:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> text = 'one “two and three” four'
>>> shlex.split(text)
['one', '“two', 'and', 'three”', 'four']
```

Using normal quotes ("), works as expected:

```
>>> text = 'one "two and three" four'
>>> shlex.split(text)
['one', 'two and three', 'four']
```

So, how do I get shlex to work with qurly/smart quotes?

Comment: I don't think you can. You can subclass `shlex.shlex` and set the `quotes` attribute to include characters other than `'` and `"`, but it appears you can't tell it to use a pair of open/close characters. When it encounters a character in `quotes`, it expects the *same* character to end the quoted string.